# C - Replace from the most to the least common letters in string1 from string2

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, histogram

I am trying to apply a cipher method.
I have tried doing a histogram, and I did not do argc argv in the main because I directly test it from there and I just call ./a.out:

```
    #include <stdio.h>                                                              
    #include <string.h>                                                             

     void cipher(const char text[], const char table[])                       
     {                                                                               
         int length = strlen(text);                                                 
         int hist[26];    //histogram for each letter of the alphabet                                        
         for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)                                    
         {                                                                           
             hist[i] = 0;                                                            
         }                                                                           
         char startletter;                                                           
         for (const char *temp = text; *temp != '\0'; temp++)                        
         {        
             startletter = *letter;                                                                   
             for (const char *letter = temp; *letter != '\0'; letter++)              
             {                                                                                                                     
                 if (*letter == startletter)                                         
                 {                                                                   
                     hist[*letter - 65] += 1;                                        
                 }                                                                   
             }                                                                       
         }                                                                           
         for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)                                            
         {                                                                           
             printf("%d ", hist[i]);                                                 
         }                                                                           
     }
```

output :

```
0 0 0 0 0 15 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 1 0 0
```

(supposed to print out the letter occurences in `string1` for now)

Comment: I have corrected my code, I will edit it it now compiles (but gives the wrong output)

Comment: What am I doing wrong

Comment: @aschancla What is it hist[i] =;?

Comment: Sorry someone edited my code I will re edit it one sec

Comment: Modified code just now

Comment: You are printing the first `strlen(table)` counts. You don't even attempt to determine which letter is the most frequent, the second most frequent, etc. The next step is to sort the letters of `text` by descending frequency. Once you have that, you can print the first `strlen(table)` sorted letters.

Comment: I see that, but I feel like the histogram does not correctly insert the letter count

Comment: Ah yes. Why is there a nested loop? All you need is `for (const char *temp = text; *temp != '\0'; temp++) 
   ++hist[*temp - 'A'];`

Comment: I wanted to compute the occurence of each letter (all F's then all X's then all O'x in this case etc). But I can just compute letter by letter I will remove the extra loop

Comment: But you end up adding 5+4+3+2+1 = 15 "F"

Comment: In fact, since you don't need to preserve `text`, all you need is `while (*text) 
   ++hist[*(text++) - 'A'];`

Comment: But the strings are const char

Comment: Don't remove the problem you're asking about from the question.

Comment: `const char*` means the character to which you point is constant, not the pointer itself. That would be `char * const`

Comment: `const char a[]` for a parameter just means `const char * text`

Comment: Ok sorry. Where do I display my updated code ?

Comment: If you wish to answer your own question, you may do so as an answer. Someone else already has, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

 void cipher(const char text[], const char table[]){
    int hist[26];    //histogram for each letter of the alphabet
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
         hist[i] = 0;

    for (const char *temp = text; *temp != '\0'; temp++)
         hist[*temp-65] += 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
         if (hist[i])
            printf("%c=%d\n", 'A'+i, hist[i]);
       }
 }

 int main(void){
     const char a[] = "FXOWFFOWOFF";
     const char b[] = "ABCD";
     cipher(a, b);
     return 0;
 }
```

All you had to do was remove the nested loop.

Comment: Thank you, now I suppose I need to : find the max in the histogram, print the letter and set it to 0 ?

Comment: @laschancla Yes, go through the table.

Answer (score 0):

you need to sort the histogram and then print letters from table according to the sorted histogram

here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void cipher(const char text[], const char table[])
{
    int length = strlen(text);

    int hist[26];    //histogram for each letter of the alphabet
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 26; i ++)
    {
        hist[i] = 0;
    }
    for (const char *temp = text; *temp != '\0'; temp++)
    {
        hist[(int)*temp - 65]++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", hist[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // sort
    int sort[26];
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    {
        sort[i] = i;
    }
    int tempint;
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < 26; ++j)
        {
            if (hist[sort[j]] > hist[sort[i]]) {
                tempint = sort[j];
                sort[j] = sort[i];
                sort[i] = tempint;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(table); ++i)
    {
        printf("%c %c\n", (char)(65 + sort[i]), table[i]);
    }
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char a[] = "FXOWFFOWOFF";
    const char b[] = "ABCD";
    cipher(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but why do we need to sort hist ? Could we find the max and print hist[i] + '0' ? then set the max to 0 and restart